Connecting to Firestore using Google.Cloud,Firestore ver 3.7 as UWP's NugetPackage
I am traing to connect to Firestore from UWP app using JSON key stored in variable jsonKey.
I instaled nuget package called Google.Cloud.Firestore version 3.7.
Now i use the code:
    var credential = GoogleCredential.FromJson(jsonKey);
    var firestoreDb = new FirestoreDbBuilder
    {
        ProjectId = projectId,
        Credential = credential
    }.Build();

Now when I compile app and app tries to connect exception occurs:
System.InvalidOperationException: „Unable to find Grpc.Core types. Please ensure you have a suitable Grpc.Core dependency”
Should I install GrpcCore nuget package or there is a way to connect using only Google.Cloud.Firestore version 3.7.
